# Function privacy and unit testing Haskell

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, private-methods

How do you deal with function visibility and unit testing in Haskell?

If you export every function in a module so that the unit tests have access to them, you risk other people calling functions that should not be in the public API.

I thought of using `{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}` and then surrounding the exports with an `#ifdef`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}

module SomeModule
#ifndef TESTING
( export1
, export2
)
#endif
where
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571/how-do-i-test-a-class-that-has-private-methods-fields-or-inner-classes

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The usual convention is to split your module into public and private parts, i.e.

```
module SomeModule.Internal where

-- ... exports all private methods
```

and then the public API

```
module SomeModule where (export1, export2)

import SomeModule.Internal
```

Then you can import `SomeModule.Internal` in tests and other places where its crucial to get access to the internal implementation.

The idea is that the users of your library never *accidentally* call the private API, but they *can* use it if the know what they are doing (debugging etc.). This greatly increases the usability of you library compared to forcibly hiding the private API.

Comment: Will this affect inlining (compile-time optimizations)? Reading https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Performance/GHC#Inlining it seems like it would... So you can either write unit tests or optimize? (please, somebody tell me that I'm wrong!)

Comment: If the concern is that the inline-once optimization will be disabled by this technique, note that you can still use explicit inlining to ensure that it happens.

Comment: For anyone trying to use this advice with Haskell-Stack, to make the `SomeModule.Internal` module, you need to create a suitable directory structure - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28193295/load-a-module-in-ghci-by-module-name-when-module-name-doesnt-match-file-name).

Answer (score 9):

For testing you normally split the application in the [cabal](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/) project file, between a library, the production executable, and a [test-suite](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#test-suites) executable that tests the library functions, so the test assertion functions are kept apart.

For external function visibility you split the library modules between the "exposed-modules" section and the "other-modules" section.

Comment: for reference here is an example of a cabal package for an executable, which is split in library and executable: http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#configurations

Comment: Can the testsuite contain tests against modules in the `other-modules` section? Unit testing internals without exposing them to outside clients sounds highly desirable to me.

Comment: @Blaisorblade yes, the way for the test-suite to access modules from `other-modules` is to specify in the cabal file `hs-source-dirs: src, tests` for the test suite. In other words the `src` is also compiled in the test suite. The downside is that you then compile your source twice: the normal way, and then again for the tests. But that's the best way I know.